# Change creation time in file in Python3

Tags: python

I am trying to change the date of creation of a file in Windows, I am doing it in python 3.6.
The problem is that the date of creation does not change by the date "2006-06-06 00:00:00", I receive as a result the date "August 21, 1970".

Code :

```
from datetime import datetime
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con

def convert_to_datetime(date):
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return datetime_object

def convert_to_integer(dt_time):
    return 10000*dt_time.year + 100*dt_time.month + dt_time.day

def changeFileCreationTime(fname, newtime):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime)
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
        fname, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)

    win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, None, None)

    winfile.close()

#

date_convert = convert_to_datetime("2006-06-06 00:00:00")
date_int = convert_to_integer(date_convert)

changeFileCreationTime("test.txt",date_int)
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Well, your function `convert_to_integer` returns 20060606, which is the number of seconds elapsed since 1970: it gives what you retrieve.

Comment: Ok, how do I modify by: 2006-06-06 00:00:00?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of my answer ? Did it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `convert_to_integer` returns 20060606, which indeed is August 21th, 1970 in number of seconds elapsed since 1970.

You should instead use the method [`datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)