# How do I get my Python script to work on a networked file?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, datetime, file-management

I am working on a script to read the creation date from a source file and change the creation dates on the destination files to match it.

It reads the creation dates for files stored locally and on the NAS.

It changes the creation dates for files stored locally.

However, I can't get it to change the creation dates for files stored on the NAS. I don't get an error message, it just doesn't change the creation date.

Any ideas of how I can get this to work? Or will I have to copy the files to a local folder, make the changes, then copy them back?

creation_dates.py

```
# Get Creation Date of source file
def get_creeation_date(fn):
    return time.ctime(os.path.getctime(fn))

# Convert datetime to integer (for conversion)
def convert_to_integer(dt_time_str):
    dt_time = datetime.strptime(dt_time_str, "%a %b  %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    return int(datetime.timestamp(dt_time))

# Change the creation date of the destination files based on the source file
# Working with module from this post: >>https://stackoverflow.com/q/47839248/11792868
def changeFileCreationTime(fname, newtime_int):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime_int)
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
        fname,
        win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ
        | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE
        | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None,
        win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        None,
    )

    win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, None, None)

    winfile.close()


def main(fn_src, fn_dest):

    changeFileCreationTime(fn_dest, convert_to_integer(get_creeation_date(fn_src)))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_src = r"\\path\to\source\file 1.mp4"                               # Located in NAS folder

    file_src_dir, file_src_name_ext = os.path.split(file_src)
    file_src_name, file_src_ext = os.path.splitext(file_src_name_ext)

    file_dest_jpg_1 = re.sub(r"(\s\d$|$)", " 2.jpg", file_src_name, 1)      # file to be created to local folder
    file_dest_jpg_2 = "\\\\path\\to\\source\\" + file_src_name + "2.jpg"    # file to be created to NAS folder
    # Also tried r"\\path\to\source\" + file_src_name + "2.jpg"

    if os.path.exists(file_dest_jpg_1) == False:
        with open(file_dest_jpg_1, "w"):
            pass
    if os.path.exists(file_dest_jpg_2) == False:
        with open(file_dest_jpg_2, "w"):
            pass

    main(file_src, file_dest_jpg_1)                                         # This works
    main(file_src, file_dest_jpg_2)                                         # This does not work
```

Comment: Many non-Windows filesystems do not store a creation time. They have the standard Unix change (`st_ctime`), modification (`st_mtime`), and access (`st_atime`) times. If available in a filesystem, a `statx` call in Linux has the birth time as `stx_btime`, but there's nothing similar to the `utimes` call that allows arbitrarily modifying the `stx_btime` value. So, even if the filesystem stores this data, I doubt the NAS would be able to change it.

Comment: UPDATE: After moving the files to a local folder, the script works to change the creation dates. However, once I copied the files to the NAS, it changed the creation dates back to original date. It seems that it copies the change or modified date to the creation date just to keep Windows happy. Guess I'll have to start sorting the NAS by modified times instead of creation times.